# HtmlTextWriter doesn't render HTML tags

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, tags, htmltextwriter

I'm creating a web user crontrol, as the following

```
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Style, "margin: 0 12px");
            output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
            output.Write("test_test");
            output.WriteEndTag("span");
```

But it only renders "test_test", without the SPAN tag. I tried several ways, but in the end only shows the text... :(

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `output.RenderEndTag()` instead of `output.WriteEndTag("span");`